# Is it possible to export an image that can be zoomed-in on?

Tags: qgis, export, resolution

I am using QGIS on a Mac.  I would like to export my map so that the viewer can zoom in on it, just as I view the map on my QGIS canvas.  I am not sure how to word what I want.  If you see the map from the zoomed-out perspective, the symbols all bunch together, you need to be able to zoom in to see the details.  Anyone have any idea if this is possible?  I tried to export a high res image in the proint composer, but its not nearly enough resolution.

Comment: What software will the recipient be using to view this map? What file format do you want the map in? Also, resolution of your image is dependent on the original source. You can only zoom in so far, and then things begin to pixelate.

Comment: You probably can't solve this problem in general - you'll need to be specific about the particular circumstance / data set that you're trying to convey here. Baltok's questions are a good start - please edit your question (just click edit below your question) to update the details.

Answer (score 2):

If you need images that can be scaled without loosing detail you may want to try exporting your map to PDF through the Print composer. This is far from being optimal, first of all because a PDF map, when viewed at a small zoom factor, can be very difficult to read or entirely impossible. PDF has also poor support for detailed vector graphic features, so if e.g. a line feature has a certain width, that will be independent on the zooming factor and will lead to lines that are too thin or too heavy depending on the viewing scale.

[image: "Zoom-all" view: left PDF, right QGIS]

[image: Detail view: left PDF, right QGIS, notice the different line width]

Another possibility is to export the map in SVG format, again from the Print composer. The same limitations described above for PDF apply.